# High battery voltage, no (noticed) symptoms, issue?

Tags: chevrolet, voltage, cruze

My dashboard screen in my `2013 Chevy Cruze` usually reads between `14.9-15.1v` lately. I've been told that this is unusually high. Given this though, I have not experienced any problems as a result of this "high voltage reading".

Do I have a problem?
What issues can arise from having a high voltage?

It's been pretty cold out lately and my car starts fine, where many others around me seem to be having battery issues.

I have not tested the battery with a multi-meter or anything of the sort, the reading is coming from the dashboard.

NOTE: Bought the car *used* with an **amplifier** installed. Not sure if that changes anything.

Comment: Just a note on the linked question - a higher voltage can make the battery operate too hot.  Since it's been cold where you are it might not be a problem at all, but once it gets worse, it could quickly kill your battery.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Funny, my answers are just about the same... And, can tell you that the voltage comes down to 14.8 so it does not overheat the battery...

Comment: @SolarMike, Yea I wouldn't worry about voltage around 15v, but if it starts to get worse and goes around 16v I'd look at replacing the regulator (which probably means the alternator)

Comment: @JPhi1618 I have a gauge I fitted to make sure I know what is happening - used to be able to draw an alternator regulator circuit from memory... So I know what I'm looking for.

Comment: This is normal for GM cars and Trucks, they run a bit higher voltage than most other brands when under a load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My car is doing the same - and it's because the demands of lights, heater etc plus the effects of the cold are making the regulator charge the battery more.

I have put a multimeter on mine and have seen 15.3V - checked the detail 2 winters ago as i had to replace the original battery (which had a date stamp showing it was 10 years old). In the summer the voltage is around 14.5 to 14.7 and I do keep an eye on it.

I did check the manual and it was in there that it can get that high - but the regulation profile is also controlled so that it will shut down the alternator as well to minimize load as it sees fit.

Either give it a good run so it gets a decent charge or charge it overnight with a good charger and see how it behaves. Once the battery is properly charged the voltage will (should) come back below 15V...